# Cloud Firestore: how to reference another document?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Angularfire2. Suppose I have a `users` and `comments` collections. When adding a comment, what would be the correct way of referencing the user who created the comment? At first I thought I could simply create a comment with a structure like this:

```
{
    message: string,
    user: {
        uid: string,
        username: string,
        ...
    }
}
```

But then the problem is if the user updates his profile, then the data here would be incorrect. Is it possible to simply supply the user's id when creating the comment and get the entire user's data when querying the comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using firestore, you can save that field as a DocumentReference which is a ref to a document in another collection. This makes it so that field acts as it's own observable inside the 'Comment' observable. This article demonstrates how to set the reference path when setting or updating a document: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/firebase-talk/UTgW7WwKFTU

Firestore offers a variety of data types explained here that are supported natively: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

I hope this can be of help!

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely up to you.  If you want duplicate the data as you are now, you'll definitely have to find a way to make sure all the copies are up to date.  If you want to just store a uid (document id), then it will cost you a second document fetch to get the user details for a message.  You are essentially trading off between cost, speed, and complexity, and there is not really a "right way" to do it.